# Function reading from standard input without any "in" parameters

Tags: ada

Perhaps this is simple, and I am just missing some basic information, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I'm writing a `Get_Word` function for class, here is the relevant section of the spec file my prof wrote:

```
function Get_Word return Ustring;
-- return a space-separated word from standard input

procedure Fill_Word_List(Wl : in out Ustring_Vector);
-- read a text file from standard in and add all
-- space-separated words to the word list wl
```

I've written the `Get_Word` function, and am trying to test it out with this code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_Io;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure ngramtest is

Name : String(1..80);
File : File_Type;
Size : Natural;

function Get_Word return String is
    -- I'm using a strings instead of Unbounded_Strings for testing purposes.
    Word : String(1..80) := (others => ' ');
    Char : Character;
    File : File_Type;
    Eol  : Boolean;
    I    : Integer := 1;
begin
    --this code below, when uncommented reveals whether or not the file is open.
    --if Is_Open(File) then
    --  Word := (1..80 => 'y');
    --else
    --  Word := (1..80 => 'n');
    --end if;
    loop
        Look_Ahead(File, Char, Eol);
        if Eol then
            exit;
        elsif Char = ' ' then
            exit;
        else
            Get (File, Char);
            Word(I) := Char;
            I := I + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return Word(1..Word'Last);
end Get_Word;

begin
    Put ("Enter filename: ");
    Get_Line (Name, Size);
    Open (File, Mode => In_File, Name => Name(1..Size));
    Put (Get_Word);
    Close(File);
end ngramtest;
```

It compiles, but at runtime I get an exception telling me that the file isn't open, and the commented out section returns "nnnnnn..." meaning that the file is not open within the function.

My question is how am I to read from standard input if i'm not allowed to use in parameters in my function? Without them the function won't be able to access files.
Essentially, how can I "Get_Word"?

Sorry if this is simple, but I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your "File" variable to standard input:

```
File : File_Type := Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Input;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Unfortunately now i have a problem where the the string "Word" isn't modified by the functions for some reason...

Comment: The function works for me. But, why does your test procedure `ngramtest` open a file when you are supposed to be reading from standard input?

Comment: @Simon Wright - Ok, let me back up. The point of `Fill_Word_List` is to read through a .txt file and return an array filled with every word in the file. It uses the `Get_Word` function to accomplish this. I'm trying to find a way to accomplish this but I can't get `Get_Word` to read a file and return a string.

I know standard input is from the keyboard without redirection, but my prof's writeup says `fill_Word_List`

`"-- reads a text file from standard in and add all space-separated --words to the word list wl"`

Do I misunderstand what standard input is? Am I not supposed to open a file?

Comment: I think the [Wikipedia article on redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) might help. You would write your program to read standard input (which is already connected, and doesn't need to be opened) and run it as `./ngramtest < data_file.txt` (you won't need the `./` if you're on Windows).